# Why does XtraBackup tell me my MySQL database is corrupt?

Tags: mysql, backup, galera, xtrabackup

I am trying to backup data on a MySQL Galera node with XtraBackup. Unfortunatelly the tool tells me, that ibdata1 is corrupt. After double checking I indeed found some myisam tables I have importet by error. Droped those and replaced them by innodb tables. However, the error remains (though on a different page now)

```
xtrabackup version 2.2.12 based on MySQL server 5.6.24 Linux (x86_64) (revision id: 8726828)
xtrabackup: uses posix_fadvise().
xtrabackup: cd to /data/mysql/data
xtrabackup: open files limit requested 0, set to 1024
xtrabackup: using the following InnoDB configuration:
xtrabackup:   innodb_data_home_dir = ./
xtrabackup:   innodb_data_file_path = ibdata1:12M:autoextend
xtrabackup:   innodb_log_group_home_dir = ./
xtrabackup:   innodb_log_files_in_group = 2
xtrabackup:   innodb_log_file_size = 50331648
>> log scanned up to (22054624442)
xtrabackup: Generating a list of tablespaces
[01] Copying ./ibdata1 to /data/backup/2015-09-02_15-23-50/ibdata1
[01] xtrabackup: Database page corruption detected at page 1320, retrying...
```

I tripple checked corruption on the database and could not find anyhthing. Is there probably a setup problem with Galera and XtraBackup?

Comment: as far as I remember Xtrabackup verifies a checksum of each page while it's copying a tablespace. Can you confirm the checksum of page 1320 is good with `innochecksum`?

Comment: That would have been a good thing to check. In the meentime I did backup all dbs with mysqldump , shutdown mysql cluster, removed the ibdata1 file & logs, restarted and recovered from backup. Now XtraBackup runs on the db without complaining. Looks like the db has really been corrupted without noticing.

Comment: Just for references: If ibdata1 gets removed on MySQL 5.6 and recreated, 5 tables will be missing! One has to restore those tables manually: http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/54608/innodb-error-table-mysql-innodb-table-stats-not-found-after-upgrade-to-mys

Comment: ibdata1 stores InnoDB dictionary, so that's expected

Comment: Somehow ibdata1 is corrupt again. I get following error after innochecksum: Fail; page 1088 invalid (fails log sequence number check). Is there a way to recover from this?

Comment: If it's just LSN (which might be a result of crashed InnoDB) then InnoDB will recover the page itself. If checksum is wrong too, I would check why it gets right after you re-created it. Hardware problems, etc .

Comment: by the way, was MySQL running? On the running MySQL you might be checking while InnoDB was writing to the page.

Comment: This is a MySQL Galera Cluster of 3. The problem apeared after I have imported a table with 1M rows. I have now redone the process, no errors so far. Let's see if it stays the same.

Answer (score 1):

This may be caused by a few different things.

- You are running an old xtrabackup version which has a bug that may flag for corruption in the data files when there is none, update to the newest xtrabackup version for your mysql version.
- There is corruption in the secondary indexes in a table

If you're able to perform a mysqldump of the tables the data should be intact and you need to either run `optimize table` or rebuild the tables. Identify ibd file corruption by checking each ibd file with `innochecksum` and use the `pt-online-schema-schema-change` application to rebuild the tables

```
pt-online-schema-change --dry-run --alter="ENGINE=INNODB" \
    --user=your_username --ask-pass \
    D=databasename,t=tablename
```

Replace the --dry-run with --execute when you want to perform the task.

- Could be caused by encryption or compression set to the table

Optimize table: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/optimize-table.html

Innochecksum: https://www.percona.com/blog/2015/03/16/deep-dive-mysqls-innochecksum-tool/

pt-online-schema-change: https://www.percona.com/doc/percona-toolkit/LATEST/pt-online-schema-change.html